# Class implementing Comparator produces IllegalStateException when probing spliterator().getComparator

Tags: java, collections, spliterator

I have following class

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {

    private String name;

    public A(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
       return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return o.getName().compareTo(this.name);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        A a = (A) o;
        return name.equals(a.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

Now my understanding is that following code should produce some class name or null but not IllegalStateException as stated in the java document which says

> If this Spliterator's source is SORTED by a Comparator, returns that Comparator. If the source is SORTED in natural order, returns null. Otherwise, if the source is not SORTED, throws IllegalStateException.

```
List<A> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new A("Y"));
arrayList.add(new A("G"));
arrayList.add(new A("J"));
arrayList.add(new A("A"));
arrayList.add(new A("Z"));

arrayList.sort(A::compareTo);
Comparator<? super A> comparator = arrayList.spliterator().getComparator();
System.out.println(comparator);
```

EDIT 2

I believe i am not able to make you understand what i am looking for.
Take this as example:

```
SortedSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>( Collections.reverseOrder() );
set.add("A");
set.add("D");
set.add("C");
set.add("B");
System.out.println(set);
System.out.println(set.spliterator().getComparator());
```

This outputs as

```
[D, C, B, A]
java.util.Collections$ReverseComparator@7852e922
```

Now Collections.reverseOrder() is just an implementation of Comparator

Since this is producing the right answer, my expectation from my code is also it should output a class name like above.

So what is that I am not doing right ?

Comment: You should override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` as well.

Comment: An `ArrayList` doesn’t remember that it has been sorted nor does it keep a reference to the `Comparator`. So the `Spliterator` does not have the `SORTED` characteristic. Besides that, don’t use `A::compareTo` as `Comparator`. Use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` or just `null` when calling `sort` on a list of `Comparable` elements.

Comment: > Otherwise, if the source is not `SORTED`, throws `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, i have implemented the hashcode and equals but to no effect, it still produces IllegalStateException.

Comment: @Holger, ok I am following you, but if they can't update their characteristics then what's the use of having getComparator(), which is never a sure shot ??

Comment: Yeah, was more a general comment on "if you implement Comparable, also override hashCode and equals". You might get weird bugs if you don't.

Comment: BTW guys, you are awesome, those were some very quick replies, thanks a lots for the efforts and time.

Comment: oh ok, point noted @JohannesKuhn, this is just a sandbox code more like understanding the concepts in depth.

Comment: You can call [`hasCharacteristics(SORTED)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#hasCharacteristics-int-) to find out.

Comment: @Holger yes I am aware of that method, but what about getComparator(), in what situations would you use it. Now since it shows ISE even after implementing Comparator, i don't know if even we can trust it's outcome in those situations or not.

Comment: You may use `getComparator()` when `hasCharacteristics(SORTED)` returned `true`. There’s no reason to distrust this logic. In your code, you didn’t check it.

Comment: @Holger thanks for bearing with me :-). Check my EDIT 2 section

Comment: But I already answered that in my first comment, an `ArrayList` doesn’t remember that it has been sorted. That’s, of course, an entirely different thing than a `TreeSet` which will even insert new elements in a way that it stays sorted, so it knows precisely that it is sorted.

Comment: Ok all right, i think i get you, so since TreeSet already has a SORTED characteristics, it would return the comparator class, but since ArrayList doesn't possess this characteristic it will always produce ISE. Would have been great if it would maintain dynamic characteristics.

Comment: any real world situation where i would really use this method ?

Comment: @Slaw yes, the reference implementation of the Stream API only eliminates redundant `sorted` operations in case of `sorted()` (no comparator) when the spliterator has a `null` comparator. There is no convincing reason for this limitation. Authors said it’s because `equals` does not always tell you when two comparators are semantically equivalent, but to me, this is no reason not to do it when it would work.

Answer (score 3):

While the characteristics of a `Spliterator` may reflect the current contents of a collection, they are usually depending on the *type* of the source collection only. So all standard `List` implementations never report the `SORTED` characteristic, even when their elements happen to be currently sorted, whereas all `SortedSet` implementations always report the `SORTED` characteristic.

You may rarely need to use this method on your own. Data processing APIs, like the `Stream` API may use the characteristics behind the scenes, to optimize the execution. For example, the `sorted` operation of a `Stream` may get skipped when it detects that the data is already sorted. But to name a less obvious example, `distinct` may work differently when the data is sorted by the element type’s natural order.

Further, the state of a stream pipeline may serve as an example of a case, where the characteristics are not determined by the type:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    check(Stream.of("foo", "bar").filter(x -> true));
    check(Stream.of("foo", "bar").sorted().filter(x -> true));
}
private static void check(Stream<?> s) {
    System.out.println("Type: "+s.getClass());
    System.out.println("sorted: "+s.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
Type: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2
sorted: false

Type: class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2
sorted: true
```

Normally, you wouldn’t use this API to get the comparator of a collection you created yourself, as you already know the comparator. But there are cases where a spliterator has a comparator not originating from your code (directly):

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));

Spliterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sp = map.entrySet().spliterator();
if(sp.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED)) {
    Comparator<? super Map.Entry<String, Integer>> comparator = sp.getComparator();
    System.out.println("Entry comparator: " + comparator);
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> e1 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("some", 5);
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> e2 = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>("string", 3);
    System.out.println(BinaryOperator.maxBy(comparator).apply(e1, e2));
}
```